# Variable declaration and initialization in Java

Tags: java, variables, scope

Where should I place this command in my code?

```
Item item = new Item();
```

I should put this inside my loop `do-while` so that it keeps on creating a new `Item` class depends on the user if how many times they want to input another product.

The problem is whenever i put that command inside my `do-while`, it cannot find the symbol `item` based on the codes at the bottom of my program. So where i should put it?

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );
    String prompt, id;
    int z = 0, choice, x = 999;
    int iprice;
    String icode;
    String iname;

    class Item {
        public int price;
        public String code;
        public String name;
    }

    ArrayList<Item> cart = new ArrayList<Item>(0);

    do {
        System.out.print("\nItem Code: ");
        icode = scan.next();
        System.out.print("Item Name: ");
        iname = scan.next();
        System.out.print("Item Price: ");
        iprice = scan.nextInt();

        item.code = icode;
        item.name = iname;
        item.price = iprice;

        cart.add(item);

        System.out.print("\tInput another? Y/N? ");
        prompt = scan.next();

    } while (prompt.equals("y"));

    System.out.println("\nWhat do you want to do?");
    System.out.println("\n1. Purchase Item ");
    System.out.println("2. List of Products ");
    System.out.println("3. Exit Program ");

    System.out.print("\n\tChoice: ");
    choice = scan.nextInt();
    if (choice == 1) {
        System.out.println("\nItem Code: ");
        id = scan.next();
        if (item.code.equals(id)) {
            System.out.println("Item Name: " + item.name);
            System.out.println("Item Price: " + item.price);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably **declare** the variable outside the loop with:

```
Item item;
```

And then you should **initialize** it at the very beginning of the loop:

```
item = new Item();
```

This way the variable is visible troughout the class, so you won´t get the error you metioned...

Also, this basically means that you are creating a new object in each loop iteration, and you are assigning this new object to the variable `item` you previously declared, so your user can create as many different items as he wants...

Note that, although you are *overriding* the variable `item` in each iteration, you won´t *lose* the object previously attached to the variable `item`, because you are adding a reference to that object into your `ArrayList<Item> cart` when you do `cart.add(item)`...

You may want to read [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) about declaration of classes and objects in Java, scopes and so on...

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys. I will surely consider and try all of those suggestions. It helps!!

Answer (score 1):

It depends. You can place it outside the loop or in  the class definition so that you can reuse the variable time and again and avoid having to create a local variable for each pass.
Something akin to:

```
Item myItem;

do{
    myItem = new Item();
    // add perfumes and shoes
    // maybe GTA 5
}while(condition)
```

You need to study, what is called, `variable scope`. That is, where you can and cannot access a variable. Here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys. I will surely consider and try all of those suggestions. It helps!!

Answer (score 1):

create new Object inside do-while loop `Item item = new Item();` i have made changes below...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO, add your application code
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
            String prompt, id; 
            int z=0, choice, x=999;
            int iprice;
            String icode;
            String iname;


            class Item {
                public int price;
                public String code;
                public String name;

            }   

            ArrayList<Item> cart = new ArrayList<Item>(0);
             Item item; // type this
                do {

            System.out.print("\nItem Code: ");
            icode=scan.next();
            System.out.print("Item Name: ");
            iname=scan.next();
            System.out.print("Item Price: ");
            iprice=scan.nextInt();


            item = new Item();  //also create new Item(); here
            item.code=icode;
            item.name=iname;
            item.price=iprice;

            cart.add(item);

            System.out.print("\tInput another? Y/N? ");
            prompt=scan.next();
            }while (prompt.equals("y"));

            System.out.println("\nWhat do you want to do?");
            System.out.println("\n1. Purchase Item ");
            System.out.println("2. List of Products ");
            System.out.println("3. Exit Program ");
            System.out.print("\n\tChoice: ");
            choice=scan.nextInt();
             if (choice==1) {

            System.out.println("\nItem Code: ");
            id=scan.next();
                    if (item.code.equals(id)) {         
            System.out.println("Item Name: "+item.name);
            System.out.println("Item Price: "+item.price);

                    }       
             }






        }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys. I will surely consider and try all of those suggestions. It helps!!